# How to reduce depth on global navbar in Plone 4

Tags: plone, theming

Using sunburst theme in Plone 4.1.2, what CSS elements and properties need to be overridden in custom CSS to reduce the depth of the global navbar? It is two lines of text deep by default, but only need one line of text.

Answer (score 2):

[Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/firebug/) or similar add-ons for browsers are your friend here. Install it (if in Firefox) or load the Console in Safari and Chrome, and select the navbar, you will see all the properties on the right pane and you will be able to play with it.

If you need more than just changing the height of the navbar, maybe it will be more useful to create a theme with [Diazo](http://diazo.org/) for the [plone.app.theming](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.app.theming) integration package for Plone. That way you will have full control over how the page is displayed.